# Which log4j facade to choose?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, string-formatting

Essentially I'm looking for something with the same behavior, configuration, logging levels as log4j, but with some of the missing functionality (e.g. formatted logging — see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920458/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946730/) for related SO threads.)

Current nominees are [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [log5j](http://code.google.com/p/log5j/).

Comment: Innocent question,  what's wrong with: logger.info(String.format("id = %d, value = %s", id, value));  :)

Comment: String.format() is processed even if the logging level is not at the info level.

Comment: There are 3 reaosons I don't like it: There's a performance penalty, the code is uglier, and the solution is really easy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm inclined toward SLF4J.

- allows [parameterized logging](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance) (formatting)
- allows [consolidation of other frameworks](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) (great for apps using many libraries, each logging to a different framework)

log5j is good, but does not have near as much market penetration.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, especially as there is a slf4j implementation to replace commons-logging.

Answer (score 3):

since a lot of frameworks already support slf4j you will only have to setup your logging once with slf4j.

i use slf4j and it is super-easy to read + use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd also suggest SLF4J, ideally with Logback.
Take a look at [What’s Up with Logging in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354837/whats-up-with-logging-in-java) and [Find a way in the java logging frameworks scene.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473065/find-a-way-in-the-java-logging-frameworks-scene), too.